# If $\sum_{i=0}^\infty x_i < \infty$, is it always true that $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=n}^\infty x_i = 0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, measure-theory

Working through a problem in Terry Tao's Measure theory book and I've reduced one of the exercises (Borel Cantelli Lemma) to proving $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \mu (\bigcup_{i=n}^\infty E_i) = 0$. By the countable subadditivity property of measures this amounts to showing that $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=n}^\infty \mu (E_i) = 0$.
We are given as an assumption that $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \mu (E_i) < \infty$. Hence the question.

Comment: Consider $x_i=\frac{1}{2^i}$

Comment: Yes, thank you Martin.

Answer (score -1):

A. it is only true if the series is absolutely convergent.
Since measures are non-negative it applies here.

B.
hint:
think of partial sums as Cauchy sequences.

Comment: Statement (A) is incorrect. All convergent series have the property.

Comment: $\sum x_i<\infty$ is not synonymous with convergence of $\sum x_i$.

Comment: It's true that $\sum x_i < \infty$ does not imply convergence in general, but the specific case I'm working with $x_i$ are strictly positive.

Comment: What if the partial sums oscillate (and is bounded) but never converges ?

Comment: @geetha290krm Ah, right, I was not considering the possibility $\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i=-\infty$, although my statement is still true as is.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio $\sum x_i$ may also be undefined (neither $+\infty$ nor $-\infty$). You should always say in words that $\sum x_i$ is convergent.

Comment: @geetha290krm I don't agree that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i<\infty$ should mean $\limsup_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i<\infty$ any more than I could agree that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)<\infty$ should mean $\limsup_{x\to\infty} f(x)<\infty$. If you speak of an object, that object should be there.

Comment: Bounded series are not necessarily convergent. Take for example the sequence $\{-(1)^n\frac{1}{2}\}$ it's series is bounded but can have 3 possible values.